# How to switch driver context from Android to webview in karate

Tags: appium, karate, appium-android

I'm working on a project to automate a mobile application using Karate and appium. The application that I'm working upon seems to be a hybrid one. When I launch the app it redirects me to a web URL to sign-in(web browser) and my karate tests are not able to locate elements present under the sign-in page.

```
Feature: android test

  Background: App Preset

    * configure driver = { type: 'android', webDriverUrl : 'xxxxx', start: false, httpConfig : { readTimeout: 120000 } }

  Scenario: android mobile app UI tests
  Given driver { webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities : "#(android.desiredConfig)"} }
  And driver.click('//android.widget.Button[@text="Get Started"]')
  # Sign details
  And click('#signInName')
  And input('#signInName', 'someone@gmail.com')
  And input('#password', '123456')
```

Comment: dev of karate here - I don't know :| by any chance can you start the browser assuming it is chrome in "debug mode" so it listens on port 9222 ? then there are options. let me ask the folks who use karate + android to comment here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

karate by default keeps you in the native app context. you can check all the context available by invoking a mobile command,

```
def contexts = driver.script("mobile: getContexts")
```

or

```
json contexts = driver.http.path("contexts").get()
```

and `print contexts`

you should be able to switch context to web-view as below (instead of `WEBVIEW_1` use your respective web-view which you got from the previous step),

```
driver.setContext("WEBVIEW_1")
```

and then switch back to native app by

```
driver.setContext("NATIVE_APP")
```

try with different locator strategies if facing any issue

Comment: I tried the above thing by setting the context before it redirects to the sign-in page and I tried to locate the element by XPath, id, and CSS selector but it didn't work for me. and FYI I also printed the driver after setting it to webview and it printed the following thing - `com.intuit.karate.driver.appium.AndroidDriver@68002219` I doubt it's not switching the context to webview even after adding `driver.setContext("WEBVIEW_1")`

Comment: Since I'm running my tests on a remote device(MobileLabs) so I'm not getting any error as such and the code isn't breaking, but I can see a message in the logs saying `"message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters."`

Comment: maybe you are having a different web-view context, updated my answer to get all available web-view for your app to decide on what to switch

Comment: As suggested I did print the contexts and this is the result I got - `[print] getContexts-> {
  "message": "Unknown mobile command \"getContexts\". Only shell,scrollBackTo,viewportScreenshot,deepLink,startLogsBroadcast,stopLogsBroadcast,acceptAlert,dismissAlert,batteryInfo,deviceInfo,changePermissions,getPermissions,performEditorAction,startScreenStreaming,stopScreenStreaming,getNotifications,listSms,type commands are supported."
}` 
I don't see any context related to `WEBVIEW_1`

Comment: seems like the initial one only works for iOS, so here is a workaround for that `def contexts = driver.http.path("context").get()`

Comment: I executed the given code i.e. 
`def contexts = driver.http.path("context").get()`
and this is the result I'm getting -
`[print] getContexts-> com.intuit.karate.Http$Response@6f8139b0`
any workaround for that?

Comment: you should be at least able to see the value from the appium logs as you were able to share the appium error messages before. or I suggest you use karate VSCode extension to debug and see the values. since you asked another workaround would be `def contexts = driver.http.path("context").get().json().get("value")`

Comment: When I ran my test script with the following code `def contexts = driver.http.path("context").get().json().get("value")` 
it throwed me an error saying -
`evaluation (js) failed: driver.http.path("context").get("value"), javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Can not invoke method [jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.SimpleDynamicMethod Response com.intuit.karate.Http.get()] with the passed arguments; they do not match any of its method signatures. in <eval> at line number 1`
Could you please confirm it once.

Comment: try `def contexts = driver.http.path("context").get().json()` but i am sure the answer is already in your logs

Comment: I tried getting the context details with the given line of code i.e.

`def contexts = driver.http.path("context").get().json()`

But ended up with the following error -

`evaluation (js) failed: driver.http.path("context").get().json(), javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: com.intuit.karate.Http$Response@285c7566 has no such function "json" in <eval> at line number 1`

I even had a deep look into the logs but couldn't find webview context name.

Comment: my bad there was a typo, try `json contexts = driver.http.path("contexts").get()` and `print contexts` if still not working please follow please follow https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue and help us reproduce the issue.

Comment: Finally, the issue was resolved. I didn't have to switch the context. Initially, while I was inspecting the elements on the sign-in page it was showing me the value of XPath in terms of normal HTML locators(E.g. //input[@text='email address']). I then switched to a different device wherein the latest version of the application was installed, and tried inspecting the elements over there and I was able to inspect the elements in terms of android locators(E.g. android.widget.webview.......so on). So by this karate was able to locate the elements on the sign-in page and the tests started working.

Comment: I would like to Thank You Babu Sekaran and @PeterThomas for your prompt assistance over the concern raised. I have to say that I'm enjoying automation testing using karate it has made the work so easy and simple :)